# Javascript find url and replace it with a link and truncate text if needed

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a function that pulls urls out of a chunk of text and replaces them with links. What I would like to do is to have the look at the length of $1 and if it is over 64chars long, I would like to replace it with something like "link". I am just not sure how to approach this.

```
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig; 
return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try -

```
var str = "http://www.yahooghghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhdf.co.uk";
str = str.replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig, function($0) { 
    if ($0.length > 60 ) return "<a href='" + $0 + "' target='_blank'>Link</a>" 
    else return "<a href='" + $0 + "' target='_blank'>" + $0 + "</a>"     
})
alert(str);
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/E7hyd/